# In SQL get all rows with same value in column A that have only non-null values in column B

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL table has multiple columns, among them A and B. In A there's some sort of identifier of some arbitrary object (say, a user or an item). Each object instance identified by A can have multiple entries in the database (A is not unique). Each object furthermore has a property B that is also stored in the database in the corresponding column B. That property can be NULL.

I now want to find all objects that have exclusively rows in the database with non-null values for B. So if there's an object A=12345 which has at least one row with B=NULL, it should be excluded. I also want to group/squash/combine the results, so that I only get a list of A's with the given condition.

For a simple and unoptimized *afoot* Python solution I could go on and solve it like this:

```py
from typing import Optional, Any
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Obj:
    A: int = 0
    B: Optional[Any] = None

Obj(0, "Test")
```

```
Obj(A=0, B='Test')
```

```py
objects = [
    Obj(0, "Test1"),
    Obj(0, "Test2"),
    Obj(0, "Test3"),
    Obj(0, "Test4"),
    Obj(1, "Test1"),
    Obj(1, "Test2"),
    Obj(1, "Test3"),
    Obj(1, None),
    Obj(2, "Test1"),
    Obj(2, "Test2"),
    Obj(2, "Test3"),
    Obj(2, "Test4"),
]
```

```py
object_As = set([o.A for o in objects])
result = []
for obj_A in object_As:
    objects_Bs_by_A = [bool(o.B is not None) for o in objects if o.A == obj_A]
    if all(objects_Bs_by_A):
        result.append(obj_A)
```

```py
result
```

```
[0, 2]
```

So, the question is: How would a proper SQL query look like for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select a
from t
group by a
having count(*) = count(b);
```

`count(b)` counts the number of non-NULL values in `b`.  This simply says that this is equal to all the rows for each `a`.

If you want the original rows, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and t2.b is null
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `t(a, b)`.

Comment: I chose to select this as the answer because it was the quickest and easiest solution (the first one with `count`, to be precise) to my particular problem. I'm sure @sam's answer would also have worked, but this one looked simpler.